# xcode iOS simulator keeps adding paired watch information

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, appium

Guys I'm having a weird annoying issue. I create a new iOS simulator without an Apple Watch and it displays with watch information, after a few minutes it displays correctly.

But every now and then it decides to add a paired watch to it at it's own. Anyone run into this issue, this causes issues with my Appium scripts, I then have to manually go in and re-create the simulator.

I also get this error the first time I run the newly created simulator.

[image]

Comment: CoreSimulator does not (by design at least) mess with the pairings of devices that it did not create.  What version of Xcode do you have?  Can you run with debug CoreSimulator logging (defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator DebugLogging -bool YES) and reproduce the issue?  Look at ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log for the debug logging.  What is the output of 'xcrun simctl list' before and after this happening?

Comment: Where is com.apple.coresimulator located? Yes It's reproducible but after a certain amount of time a few days or so, or after a few full shutdowns. I'm using the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: com.apple.coresimulator is an identifier.  What do you mean by "Where is com.apple.coresimulator located?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is an issue if you have only one simulator installed. What I did was delete the whole CoreSimulator folder and remake a few simulators, now the issues are gone.

But if you leave only one simulator it will give you issues.